# Why is this N-type MOSFET always on with my PCB?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design

MOSFET: https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_BORN-AO3400A_C344010.pdf

Images: https://imgur.com/a/tRBPVMB

https://imgur.com/a/66Hsdpb

When COIL_ACTV is set to HIGH from my micro-controller (ESP-32). I want to allow current to run through LED_COIL. LED_COIL and R4 will be replaced with a 1.4 ohm resistor once I verify the circuit works correctly.

However, it seems current is constantly running through the LED. Why? I notice when I set COIL_ACTV to HIGH the LED_COIL does become brighter and when I set COIL_ACTV back to low LED_COIL becomes dimmer which means it is partially working.

Why is the MOSFET constantly on? How can I prevent this?

I have a flyback/flywheel diode in place for when I place my 1.4 ohm coil in place of LED_COIL and R4.

I have one suspicion, could this be occurring because I am connecting my flyback diode directly to the load before the MOSFET?

Comment: 1. Get a meter. 2. Put it in Vdc, 3. Start measuring. 4. Report back

Comment: please attach the pictures by using the mountain button

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the current is flowing into the CE pin of the TP4056. You should not exceed the Vcc of the TP4056 if you don't want that to happen.

One possible solution would be to add a second MOSFET but there's probably an easier way.